# How can add a new column in df1 called value that looks up the value from df2 based on the year column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames,

df1

```
Name    Year
A       2008
A       2009
B       2008
B       2008
```

df2

```
year    value
2008    10
2009    15
```

How can add a new column in df1 called value that looks up the value from df2 based on the year column?

Goal

```
Name  Year  Value
A     2008  10
A     2009  15
B     2008  10
B     2009  15
```

My issue ended up being datatypes..

```
 df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

The map solution was the fastest with 76,000 rows

Comment: Are you sure about the goal? Your df1 B years are 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use map

```
df1['value'] = df1['Year'].map(df2.set_index('year')['value'])
```

You get

```
    Name    Year    value
0   A       2008    10
1   A       2009    15
2   B       2008    10
3   B       2008    10
```

Comment: Solid answer! PlusOne

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [pd.merge()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on your `Year` column.

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='Year', how='left')
```

Comment: `'year'` is not the same as `'Year'`.  You want `df1.merge(df2, left_on='Year', right_on='year', how='left')` and then `drop('year', 1)` afterwards.  Plus One ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `join` to achieve this

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('year'), on='Year')

  Name  Year  value
0    A  2008     10
1    A  2009     15
2    B  2008     10
3    B  2008     10
```